# Find package name using terminal

Tags: command-line, package-management

Hello I want to remove software (for example transmission) using Terminal. How can i find the package name for the software ?

Comment: Do you know about the auto-complete feature in apt-get? If you enter 'apt-get remove tra', and then press tab twice, it will show all the packages starting with tra.

Comment: auto-complete doesn't work for me 10.10

Comment: Are you sure? Have you tried with other package names, but ones you know are installed?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

search for it using

```
apt-cache search name
```

like

```
apt-cache search transmission
```

gives:

```
conkytransmission - Transmission torrent info, for use in Conky
transgui - Remote GUI for Transmission daemon     
transmission - lightweight BitTorrent client
transmission-cli - lightweight BitTorrent client (command line interface)
transmission-common - lightweight BitTorrent client (common files)
transmission-daemon - lightweight BitTorrent client (daemon)
transmission-gtk - lightweight BitTorrent client (GTK interface)
transmission-qt - lightweight BitTorrent client (Qt interface)
```

at the last (the most relevant results will be at the last since it is the terminal)

Comment: I don't know why but the PACKAGE NAME transmission doesn't work.

Comment: My question was: How can I find the PACKAGE NAME of an application for further removing it by typing its name in terminal?

Comment: You can also try dpkg -l|grep -i transmission to locate package names associated with it.

Comment: `apt-cache search` is not suitable for listing **installed** packages.

Comment: but alfalive is asking how to find the package name so software can be installed.

Comment: "remove" is not install IMO :P. Corrected a typo

Comment: This is CRAZY!!! to many editors. Are you able to look into edit history? I should ask question and make screenshot of it. And then upload it here:) The original question was a little bit different.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 11):

To query installed packages we can use powerful search functions from [DPKG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dpkg) package management:

- `dpkg-query --list 'pattern*'` lists all **packages** that have not been purged
- `dpkg-query --search 'pattern*'` searches for individual **files** installed

You can use wildcards in the search pattern to find packages when only part of the package name is known.

Answer (score 4):

If you're trying to remove a package

```
apt search transmission | grep installed
```

will only display installed packages

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about what this command does. A plain command or command sequence is rarely considered an answer. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)

Comment: Best answer, replace transmission with something of the name of your app and wuolah