# search command for packages in Ubuntu terminal to search updates and patches of the package specifically

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, java, search, jdk

Can I know what is the command to search any package using the terminal, if I only know the name of the Software like, if I want to search VLC or JDK,JRE.. etc

If I do not know what is the url where I get them to download I might search them through the internet, but downloading them and extracting them and then installing becomes a lengthy procedure.

So I wanted to know is there any command to search the package via their names or part of names?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find package name using terminal](http://askubuntu.com/questions/32238/find-package-name-using-terminal)

Comment: Are you really interested in finding updates/patches too? In that case this question is not a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/32238/find-package-name-using-terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Nick already pointed out, `apt-cache search QUERY` should list packages containing specific string in their names.

Another useful tool is `apt-file`. `apt-file search QUERY` will print list of packages containing files with `QUERY` in their names. In some cases you know the name of a binary needed (like when you are reading a tutorial and need some command not installed in your OS) but do not know what package it comes with.

Also, `dpkg -S QUERY` lists **installed** packages which provide files containing 'QUERY' in their names. In some cases you have a binary or script installed on one machine and want it also on another one, but do not remember where it came from. The output should be smaller than for `apt-file` in this case, as it does not display content of packages not installed.

You may filter output of those commands with `egrep`, say with `egrep '/NAME$'`.

e.g. `dpkg -S ps | egrep '/bin/ps$'` tells us that `ps` binary comes with `procps` package.

Comment: can the search command have any modifications or extensions so that it can search any of the updates or patches that the package has undergone

Answer (score 1):

In the command line you can use

```
apt-cache search SearchTerm
```

Of course you have to change "SearchTerm" to the piece of text you already know. But there is also a webinterface for searching packages under [Ubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com/). I think the search function of the Ubuntu Software Center may be helpful.