# How do I remove thundar file browser?

Tags: unity, xfce4

I run Ubuntu 12.04 and after I removed XFCE4, the file browser did not go away. I tried `sudo apt-get remove thundar` with no success... Someone help me find the name of this package so I can remove it off my machine.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/336477/how-do-i-remove-thunar-file-browser ?

Answer (score 1):

The package name is `thunar`, not `thundar`. Try with `sudo apt-get remove thunar`.

Comment: I feel like an idiot now. Thanks alot for fixing my eyes :)

Comment: np. If you don't remember the exact package name, you might use tab completion (just press `tab` after the first letter, or second etc.), it should show a list of commands starting with those letters. If the binary you want to get rid of does not match package name, try one of the methods described in http://askubuntu.com/questions/336651/search-command-for-packages-in-ubuntu-terminal-to-search-updates-and-patches-of/336663#336663 If this answer solved your problem, please make it accepted by clicking the 'tick' below the vote count ;)