# Is there any way I can get a package name from terminal?

Tags: command-line, package-management, 3g

I had a software (internet dongle) installed in my Ubuntu 14.04. The day before yesterday I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and I found, *that software* is not working. I tried reinstalling the package, but it's stating that, it's already installed. So I thought to remove it first, to reinstall it in new version of Ubuntu.

But the package is not listed in Ubuntu Software Center, and I'm afraid I don't know the package name of the software so that I can uninstall from terminal.

The software/dongle package is known in human-understandable form as: "Teletalk 3G". I [searched](https://askubuntu.com/a/32239/351926) my PC with:

```
sudo apt-cache search tel*
```

and all sorts of combination like: `*3g*`, `*talk*` etc. But I found no trace of a package that I can relate with Teletalk 3G.

I've the `install.sh` and the installer `PCL_TLKBGL.tar.gz` file (I also tried with `PCL_TLKBGL`, but no luck). **Can I found any trace what machine name is used for the package when installed**, so that I can uninstall the package from terminal?

**PS:** Without that dongle I'm out of Internet in my Ubuntu installation. I'm asking *this* from my Windows installation, where the dongle is working fine.

Comment: That software is not an apt package and you won't find it with `apt-cache search`

Comment: Look at this: https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1800

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: @willem.hill I used the link before, and bookmarked, but without knowledgeable eye ashes can't be valuable resource :). Thanks for the link again, it meant something to me with the answer by heemayl.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apt-cache search` searches the local package database of enabled repositories, in relevant files within `/var/lib/apt/lists/` directory, as presumably the package is not available in any of your enabled repositories, you are not getting anything expectedly.

There are different techniques to install packages from any user (compressed) archived file like the one you have (`PCL_TLKBGL.tar.gz`) by (usually) extract, create, copy cycle. The installation and uninstallation instructions should be written inside some file within the archive, possibly a `README`.

Now, as you have used a `install.sh` script to install the package, there might be a `uninstall.sh` or there could be some method mentioned, you never know. So extract that compressed archive (`PCL_TLKBGL.tar.gz`) you have and check inside for any hint.

As a side note, if you use `sudo make install` as the last stage of installation (this will copy relevant files to mentioned directories), you should look at `checkinstall` instead to create a `.deb` archive out of the files and easily maintain/remove using package managers.

Comment: That `uninstall.sh` showed me the way. Used @willem.hill's [comment](http://askubuntu.com/questions/821288/is-there-any-way-i-can-get-a-package-name-from-terminal?noredirect=1#comment1246176_821288) to locate the `uninstall.sh` it's not located into the `.tar.gz` it's inside another `.tar.gz` inside the first one. Okay, uninstalled the app successfully. But the app is not compatible with 16.04 so the problem persists. Anyway, thanks a lot for showing me the way.