# How do I confirm that I have found the correct package name?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, configuration, bug-reporting

I appear to be experiencing a bug with 'Backups' and wish to report it. [To do so](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs), I must [find the package name](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32238/find-package-name-using-terminal). However, given a list of possible options, how do I know which one it is?

Namely, I surmise in this case it is 'deja-dup', but I wish to confirm before filing the bug report. How do I so?

```
$ sudo apt-cache search backups
[sudo] password for user: 
backuppc - high-performance, enterprise-grade system for backing up PCs
deja-dup - Back up your files
rsync - fast, versatile, remote (and local) file-copying tool
tar - GNU version of the tar archiving utility
[roughly one hundred other options are listed]
```

Trying a different search method:

```
$ apt search backups | grep installed | cat -b

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

     1  deja-dup/xenial-updates,now 34.2-0ubuntu1.1 amd64 [installed]
     2  rsync/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 3.1.1-3ubuntu1.1 amd64 [installed]
     3  tar/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.28-2.1ubuntu0.1 amd64 [installed]
```

My only guess on how to confirm is to try executing the command hoping to open the same 'Backups' Graphical User Interface, but it appears dangerous or poor practice to execute commands without knowing what they will do.

Comment: Find the command for the Backups program using https://askubuntu.com/questions/126268/how-to-find-out-the-terminal-command-of-an-application, then use https://askubuntu.com/questions/481/how-do-i-find-the-package-that-provides-a-file to find which package it came from.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question specifically for the deja-dup package. I would appreciate an answer applicable to any package, not only default unity-control-center packages, but you appear to have given this answer in a comment implying that it depends on the situation. I still do not yet understand why users sometimes post answers as comments instead of as answers.

Comment: I closed it as a duplicate and explained in the comment why it's a duplicate of those two.

Comment: And I don't see how those posts are only applicable to "unity-control-center" packages.

Comment: You are correct that now, taking all the citations together, the response is generally applicable. I first saw only one suggestion of a duplicate that specifically was to check /usr/share/applications (this seems too specific an answer), but then you added other references to generalize to other cases. Are answers inappropriate to duplicate questions because they would 'rob' the original answerers of additional reputation?