# ifconfig missing after Ubuntu 18.04 install

Tags: command-line, 18.04, ubuntu-minimal, ifconfig

I've just installed Ubuntu 18.04 and selected "minimal install". I then tried to run `ifconfig` in the terminal and got the following message

```
-bash: ifconfig: command not found
```

How come the [`net-tools` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/net-tools) is not installed by default any more?

Comment: @dessert True. Maybe you can tell me if the `fc-cache` command is a defualt package or not?

Comment: @JiiB On a box without a GUI? No, probably not. And a *minimal* install would be without X.

Comment: I edited your question to address solely `ifconfig` because it would be considered too broad and possibly primarily opinion-based as it was. If you're asking about other specific commands/packages as well, please [ask a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) for them.

Comment: You might be interested in [how to find a package name by the command name](https://askubuntu.com/q/32238/507051) and [How do I list the default installed packages?](https://askubuntu.com/q/48886/507051).

Comment: apt install -y net-tools

Answer (score 222, accepted):

`ifconfig` is [deprecated, and has been so for quite a number of years](https://serverfault.com/questions/458628/should-i-quit-using-ifconfig). The new kid in town is the `ip` command, which can configure IP's, routes, and everything associated with networks.

You can install `ifconfig` with `sudo apt install net-tools`, if you absolutely need to have it. If not, start learning `ip`.

In short, it is removed because you should not use it. It has mediocre IPv6 support, the `ip` command is a better replacement. I find sources saying ifconfig was deprecated back in 2012, so I'm not surprised it's finally removed.

You may be able to install it on 18.04, but on future releases it may disappear entirely. I would consider it not being installed by default as a warning shot: learn `ip`.

Thus `ifconfig` is probably in a special class. In previous versions of Ubuntu it was included in minimal installs. It is now being phased out, and you explicitly have to install it. This can not be taken to indicate that any other packages are missing.

Comment: To further clarify, the command ip is included in the minimal installation of Ubuntu 18.04, no need to install anything additional.

Comment: You may find `ifconfig` installed, if you install one of the various packages which still haven't been updated to use `ip`, or if you upgraded from an older release of Ubuntu. But you should be aware that `ifconfig` may not be present on modern systems, and should not rely on it. And actually [`ifconfig` was deprecated _in 2009_](https://serverfault.com/q/633087/126632).

Comment: Use `ip -c a` to highlight the IP addresses with colors.

Comment: @jingyu9575 you changed my life

Comment: I find it rather disturbing that  `ip a` for me still has some color in it even without a `-c`.  Admittedly not of recent vintage, still...

Comment: on further examination the color I saw is some side effect in mobaxterm magically trying to help

Comment: Minimalist Docker installs may not have `ip` installed, do `apt install -y iproute2` in those cases.

Comment: Is the ipv6 reason the only one to justify deprecation of ifconfig? Because henostly, ipv6 is not that much used and I doubt sys admin use it every day as we do with ipv4.

Comment: @FlorianCastelain  IPv6 adoption is a rather bad excuse; it is happening, it's gaining momentum, and everyone agree that we have to do it. Poor tools will not make adaption faster, so if tools change to aid adaption to IPv6, it's good - not bad...

Comment: more better way to see `ip -c -o -f inet add`

Comment: A more concise/readable option, surprisingly, is to check the routes (`ip -c r`).

Answer (score 41):

as addition to @vidarlo answer, you can put `alias ifconfig='ip -c a'` to `.bash_aliases` if you have typing habit.

Answer (score 11):

This makes the copying of IP addies simpler:

```bsh
alias ifconfig="ip -c a | sed -e 's/\// \//g'"
```

(otherwise that subnet slash prevents doubleclick->select of only the IP)

Answer (score 1):

I had to do:

```
sudo apt-get install net-tools
sudo apt autoremove
```

I guess that the second line be optional.

My runtime system:
   Operating System: Ubuntu 18.04