# i am getting an error when i excute ifconfig command on my virtual machine. (ubuntu 18.04 LTS)

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Hi every one i have a problem after creating a virtual machine in my virtual box my host OS is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

I am setting the network as shown in the photo below so i can practice in http verb tampering but when i start the machine and try to read the `ip` address of the system via `ifconfig` command it gives an error as you see below notice that when i attache adapter1 to NAT every thing working good ad i can run the `ifconfig` command without any issues in reading the `ip address`.

I hope that what i am saying is clear to you. I am just a beginner in this please help me to solve this problem.

[image: the network setting for the virtual machine]

the result from executing ifconfig command in the virtual machine
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Can please copy and paste those text from the image...

Comment: eth0 Link encap:ethernet HWaddr 08:00:27:EF:AE:67 UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metriic:1

Comment: is this enough for you

Comment: The best way to add additional information to your question is by editing it, with the [edit] button. It is better visible that way, and comments are mainly for secondary, temporary purposes. Comments are removed under a variety of circumstances. Anything important to your question should be in the question itself.

Answer (score 1):

`ifconfig` is no longer supported (by default) in Ubuntu.
you can use a tool with nearly the same actions which is `ip`, for example if you want to check your wireless card IP address it can be done as follow:
`ip address show`
If you really need `ifconfig` it can be installed using this command `sudo apt install net-tools`
For a detailed answer you can refer to this comment [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1031645/578265)