# Why I get error Failed to execute child process "/sbin/ifconfig" when opening Nutty?

Tags: networking, monitoring, traffic

I am in Ubuntu 18.04, I installed Nutty using command

```
sudo snap install nutty
```

while trying to open using

```
sudo nutty
```

I got this error:

```
[_LOG_LEVEL_WARN 03:18:10.669274] nutty.vala:1248: Error encountered in execution of sync command [/sbin/ifconfig -s]: Failed to execute child process "/sbin/ifconfig" (Permission denied)
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 03:18:10.669342] string_strip: assertion 'self != NULL' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 03:18:10.669371] Nutty will not function properly.
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 03:18:10.669409] [GLib] g_strsplit: assertion 'string != NULL' failed
[_LOG_LEVEL_FATAL 03:18:10.669437] Nutty will not function properly.
**
ERROR:arraylist.c:1175:gee_array_list_real_remove_at: assertion failed: (index < _size)
Aborted
```

Any ideas will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `ifconfig` command is provided by the `net-tools` package, which is no longer installed by default on 18.04. It is deprecated in favour of the more versatile `ip` command. Also see [ifconfig missing after Ubuntu 18.04 install](https://askubuntu.com/q/1031640/367990) for more info.

What you could try is to install that package anyway, as it is still available in the repositories:

```
sudo apt install net-tools
```

After that the missing `/sbin/ifconfig` command should be available, but I can't say whether it would be able to work correctly with the rest of 18.04's new networking stack and with your snap application. If it fails, remove that package again.

As a long-term solution, you should file a bug report for the maintainer of your `nutty` snap package and ask them to update their software to use `ip` instead of `ifconfig` from now on.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. Actually I had already installed `net-tools` before installing `nutty`. Maybe i must report this bug for Nutty maintainer.