# python3 not working in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

The command 'python3' not working when I try to check my connection status in ubuntu18.04. 
In the terminal the output looks like the following

```
bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

`which python3` doesn't print anything to the terminal.
Can anybody help me figure out what the problem might be?

Comment: This is two questions. [`ifconfig` is depreceated and has been so for a long time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1031640/ifconfig-missing-after-ubuntu-18-04-install). In addition, you seem to have a broken `python3` installation. I suggest you remove your question about `ifconfig` and focus on python3.

Comment: @vidarlo edited the question as such

Comment: The *problem* is that you somehow broke Python3. There are several ways to do so, and it's Bad News. Apt and other essential system services depend upon a functioning Python3. The *solution* is generally to reinstall the `python3.7` package. You probably need to use dpkg to do so, since apt is likely broken.